# Turning on a webapp's functionality using a button in another webapp

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

**I have two different web apps (designed using Django) which are deployed on different servers and running independently.**

I am searching for the following pointers:

1. Imagine there is a functionality X in webapp1 and a button1 in webapp2.
2. When button1 is pressed (webapp2), the X1 functionality(webapp1) must be activated.

Comment: You can just send a http request to the other server.

Comment: Turning on? activated? do you mean that the function is not accessible until the button1 is pressed?

If you're just looking to execute a function that is in webapp1 from webapp2 then just create an api in webapp1 that executes the function.